# get random rows from RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to get back N random rows from a sparkSQL RDD, something like this:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT col FROM tablename").sample(true, .7, 98712).show()
```

The .7 and 98712 are just junk numbers I'm using to play with.

I'm not really seeing random results and would like to know how to get some random rows back from an RDD?

Comment: I think this is probably because you are manually setting a constant seed with your third argument (98712). If you remove that, you should see random results ([like the scala doc implies](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)).

Comment: thanks, turns out that was half the issue. the other half was the .7 was too large. I changed it to like .000001 and the results appear much more random. feel free to put a fuller answer and I'll accept, or I will. thanks

Comment: Sure, thanks! Also, are you saying that with a 0.7 fraction, you were not seeing random rows?

Comment: I think it was random, but I was not seeing a big selection of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be because your third argument manually sets a seed versus a random one being chosen for you. From the DataFrame implementation, here are the two methods for sampling:

```
/**
 * Returns a new [[DataFrame]] by sampling a fraction of rows.
 ...
 */
def sample(withReplacement: Boolean, fraction: Double, seed: Long): DataFrame = {
  Sample(0.0, fraction, withReplacement, seed, logicalPlan)
}

/**
 * Returns a new [[DataFrame]] by sampling a fraction of rows, using a random seed.
 ...
 */
def sample(withReplacement: Boolean, fraction: Double): DataFrame = {
  sample(withReplacement, fraction, Utils.random.nextLong)
}
```

Just remove the third argument to have random rows returned.